# Getting a UILabel to appear above a UINavigationBar

Tags: xcode4

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UILabel *header = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 320, 10)];
header.text = @"Test";
header.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];
header.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
header.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Zapfino" size: 14.0];
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.view addSubview:header];
```

This is my code. When I position the UILabel, it won't float over the navigationBar.  Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the label as a subview of the navigation bar, not `self.view`:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:header];
```

Comment: Sorry to accept this 3 years late, I was too young to understand how to use stackoverflow then.